# pass data from html to controller ruby on rails

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi i want to send the selected object to a controller method but I dont know how. this is the select list with the vaules in it

Html------------

```
<%= form_tag '/wendy' do %>
  <%= select_tag :'buenwendy', options_from_collection_for_select(@cursitos, 'id', 'name') %>
  <%= submit_tag 'buscar', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
post 'wendy', to: 'blog#wendy
```

Controller------------------------------

```
def wendy
  gg= params[:buenwendy]
  flash[:success]= gg
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: `options_from_collection_for_select(@cursitos, 'id', 'name')` from where `@cursitos` is comming?

Comment: it is a SQL query:     @cursitos = Course.find_by_sql("SELECT courses.name FROM courses, cours_sts, students WHERE courses.id = cours_sts.course_id AND students.id = cours_sts.student_id AND students.id= 1")

Answer (score 1):

try this: after selecting course you will get can find that course at controller side and storing it in @gg variable
HTML...........

```
<%= form_tag( '/wendy', :method => :post ) %>
  <%= select_tag :'buenwendy', options_from_collection_for_select(@cursitos, 'id', 'name') %>
  <%= submit_tag 'buscar', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

......routes

```
post '/wendy', to: 'blog#wendy
```

controller..........

```
def wendy
  @gg= Course.find(params[:buenwendy])
  flash[:success]= @gg
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: `gg` or `@gg`?.

Comment: if this variable is to be used on view page then it should be stored in instance variable thats why i used @gg instead of gg

Comment: I meant because the flash was setted to a local variable which I hadn't seen in that "scope".

Comment: yep, i got your point of view , anyway i have modified the answer , thanks for correct me

Comment: Still not sending data guys :/

Comment: @RosalbaLancheros lets try modified answer?

Comment: yes i did. this is what the console shows:
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qWxpIduo8CI1Qh6B1Izb1ZTD1I6RHc8+cbl0rsVodBCIcYrdFp13Z2bQmsPMqdteM6DmPxuTXtul6WtLOK+eIg==", "buenwendy"=>"", "commit"=>"buscar"}

Answer (score 0):

I solved it guys, I had to get the id of @cursitos from the SQL query

```
@cursitos = Course.find_by_sql("SELECT *courses.id*, courses.name FROM courses, cours_sts, students WHERE courses.id = cours_sts.course_id AND students.id = cours_sts.student_id AND students.id= 1")
```